Podman Desktop: Can't start any container - why?
We develop within WSL and already are using podman in there. I now installed Podman Desktop and configured our Nexus (registry), and everything works fine with pulling images etc.
However, if I want to start a container, nothing happens. Somehow I managed to get the "start" icon to do something in another view, but then it just hung in the "start circle" icon indefinitely.
If I start a container using podman in WSL, it appears in Podman Desktop, and I can stop it.
But there seems to be no way to start one. I do see the event in WSL with the status 'create' and the name of my image, but that's about it.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to debug my problem?
And regarding installation: If I understand it right, Podman Desktop installs its own Podman. Is there any way to have it run the existing Podman installation?

I'm not an experienced Linux user  :-)  Anyway, for future people looking for this: It seems that this is not possible unless you have systemd running. This was not the case for my WSL and comes only with newer WSL versions.
